# get values based on foreign key

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

i have two tables:

Acounts:

```
ID    Name
1     cash
2     bank
3     credit card
```

Transactions

```
ID   accounts_id   details    income    expenses
1    1              abc        1000        0
2    1              xyz           0      500
3    2              avc         200        0
```

what i want is to get the sum of income and expenses column for all the accounts in account table (even if there is not record in the transaction table for that account_id)

required output:

```
account_id    total_income    total_expenses
 1                 1000             500
 2                  200               0
 3                    0               0
```

what i am trying in sql:

```
select account_id,coalesce (sum(income),0) as total_income,coalesce(sum(expenses),0) as total_expenses from transactions where account_id in (select id as accounts_id from accounts) group by account_id
```

what the above query gives:

```
account_id    total_income    total_expenses
 1                 1000             500
 2                  200               0
```

account with ID=3 is not included in the result..

i know i am doing something wrong.. or may be completely wrong..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get all the accounts in the account table.  To do that, you need a `join`, specifically an `outer join`:

```
select a.account_id, coalesce(sum(t.income),0) as total_income,
       coalesce(sum(t.expenses),0) as total_expenses
from accounts a left join
     transactions t
     on a.account_id = t.account_id
group by a.account_id;
```

Your attempt to do this in the `where` clause is counterintuitive.  The `where` clause *filters* values, so it reduces the number of rows; it cannot increase the number.

Comment: thank you for your solution and explaining my mistake.. but do me a little favor..

i just found a solution myself. please let me know if this would be the right way or  am i repeating my mistake??

the below query gives me the desired output:

select id ,name, (select coalesce (sum(income),0) from transactions where account_id=accounts.id),(select coalesce (sum(expenses),0) from transactions where account_id=accounts.id) from accounts

Comment: Are you sure those coalesce are really necessary? SUM should return 0 even if all values are null, AFAIK

Comment: @Frazz i was working on another application where i added a column using alter query, that column was having null values.. so when i performed sum on that column it returned me null.. 

so sum may return null..

Comment: @Frazz i just tested the query given by Gordon, it is working just fine as i want.. 

but if i remove coalesce from the query.. it gives me NULL..

Comment: Use NVL function.The COALESCE expression is a syntactic shortcut for the CASE expression

Comment: @Tarun . . . Using correlated subqueries would be another way to do the calculation.  Under some circumstances, it might even perform better than the `group by` method.  However, the join-and-aggregate method would typically be the more "SQL" way to approach the problem.

Comment: @VJMaestro . . . `coalesce()` is ANSI standard. `NVL()` is database-specific.  I generally prefer ANSI-standard functionality when I have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
          WITH TEMP AS
          (
            SELECT A.ID,T.*
            FROM ACCOUNTS A INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS T 
            ON A.ID=T.ID
          )
          SELECT ACCOUNT_ID,SUM(INCOME) AS INCOME,SUM(EXPENSE) AS EXPENSE FROM TEMP
          GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID;
```